# How to use LIKE operator on a query of sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

```
sequelize.query('(..) WHERE LOWER(u.NOMBRE) LIKE "LOWER(:find)%" AND u.ACTIVO = 1 ', {replacements: {find: req.params.usuario, id: req.session.passport.user}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

Comment: Please translate your question to english or use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: StackOverflow guidelines for non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to use $like based on your question:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const user = User.findAll({ // or User.findOne
    where: {
        activo: 1, // your search condition
        [Op.like]: [
            { nombre: req.params.nombre } // your $like params
        ],
    }
    attributes: ['id', 'nombre'] // results you want returned
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You gotta use this code:

```js
import { Op } from "sequelize";

const { sentence } = req.body;

const result = await Model.findAll({
  where: {
    column: {
      [Op.like] : `%${sentence}%`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
form(action="/search" method="POST" class="flex gap-4 items-center")
      input(type="text", id="sentence" name="sentence" placeholder="" class="p-2 rounded-lg shadow text-sm")

      input(type="submit", class="bg-[#4C4B16] hover:scale-105 px-2 py-1 rounded-lg text-white uppercase font-bold cursor-pointer text-sm")
```